# Issue while hitting the server

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am getting following error when I am hitting a URL but I am able to hit this URL from within my terminal. Not able to figure out whats going wrong...

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo=0x6c95e30
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://18.209.7.191:8080/MyService/test/location/viewLocations.plist,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://18.209.7.191:8080/MyService/test/location/viewLocations.plist,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The request
>   timed out.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6c938b0 "The
>   request timed out."

Please suggest.

Comment: which is the correct URL, the one starting with 17. or 18.?

Comment: What do you mean by "from within my terminal"? do you mean a command line tool?

Comment: Using "curl" command I am able to hit his URL.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite perplexing...

Step 1) put in http://google.com/ in your code and see if you get a time out.  That will tell you if it's network related or not.

Step 2) Implement *every* NSURLConnection delegate method and see which ones get called.  This should give you more hints.

8080 makes it sound like you have a custom webserver running somewhere.  check the logs to see if the request is even getting to the server.

Comment: I did that but it still does not give any response. Is there any settings on my machine I am missing. I tested the code from another machine and it works.